# make a block element inside a list not fall into the next line

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to make a block element inside a list not fall into the next line?

```css
li{
  list-style-type:decimal;
  list-style-position:inside;
}
div{
  display:table-cell;
}
/*make P element display:inline is not what I want*/
```

```html
<li><p>Pellentesque  habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p></li>

<h3>The following is what I want:</h3>
<div>1. </div><div>Pellentesque  habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the list-style indicator and p element to be side-by-side, get rid of:

```
  list-style-position:inside;
```

You might have to tweak the padding/margin on parent element, but this will allow the side by side layout you are looking for.

Comment: Yeah, it works! But why `ul` has to be there? I thought it was optional. Remove `ul` or replace it with `div`, then it won't work. Do you know why?

Comment: why `li` has  a parent tag restriction?

Comment: Per the spec, only <ol> and <ul> can contain <li>. Spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-li-element, Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803630/li-without-parent-tags. With invalid HTML, browsers may try to render the markup, albeit differently from one another and your expectation.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the `<li`> inside `<ol>`. Also remove the css: `list-style-type:decimal;` & `list-style-position:inside;`

```
<ol>
  <li>
    <p>Pellentesque  habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et 
    malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, 
    feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu 
    libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. 
    Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
  </li>
</ol>
```