# How do I make "Enter" keypress in an <input> Element shift focus to the next <input> element on the page. (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

How do I make make  an <kbd>Enter</kbd> keypress in an `<input>` element shift focus to the next `<input>` element on the page?

I have a for loop that creates `<li>` elements with `<input>` elements inside. I need to make so that when the user hits enter on their keyboard, the website will focus on the next input field so that the user can enter the next player name without having to toggle between using their mouse and their keyboard.

I thought using the `nextSibling` property was the solution but it wont work because the `<input>` elements technically dont have any siblings because each of them is inside/are children of diferent `<li>` elements.

Here is my JavaScript:

```
for ( var i = 1 ; i <= numberOfPlayers ; i++ ){
  var inputElement = document.createElement('input');
  var liElement = document.createElement('li');
  inputElement.setAttribute( 'type' , 'text' );
  inputElement.setAttribute ( 'id' , 'name-input-' + i );
  inputElement.setAttribute ( 'class' , 'name-input');
  inputElement.setAttribute ( 'placeholder' , 'Enter a name for player ' + i );
  liElement.appendChild(inputElement);
  nameInputArray[i] = inputElement;
  document.getElementById('name-list').appendChild(liElement);
  inputElement.addEventListener( 'keypress' , function(event){
    if ( event.which === 13 ) {
      alert(this);
      document.getElementById( 'name-input-' + (i+1)).focus();
    }
  } );
}
```

I tried using the "i" in the for loop and string concatenation to select the ID of the next element but the "i" variable isn't working either because by the time that code runs that "i" is equal to the highest number that it can be after the whole for loop has ran.

Comment: you need to learn about closures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:**

The problem with your actual code is that `i` is always equal to `numberOfPlayers+1` in the event handler `callback` function, so you were trying to focus on a `null` element, you can read more about [**JavaScript closures**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) to see why `i` was always equal to `numberOfPlayers+1`.

**Solution:**

First you need to use the `onkeypress` event on your input, then test if the pressed key is the <kbd>Enter</kbd>, if it's pressed get the `id` of the current `input`, extract `i` value from it and focus on the next `input` element using the next `id`.

This is how should be your code:

```
inputElement.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
    if (event.which === 13) {
         var i = parseInt(this.id.charAt(this.id.length-1));
         console.log(i);
         if(i<=numberOfPlayers){
            document.getElementById('name-input-' + (i + 1)).focus();
         }
    }
});
```

This is a working snippet:

```js
var numberOfPlayers = 5;
var nameInputArray = [];

for (var i = 1; i <= numberOfPlayers; i++) {
  var inputElement = document.createElement('input');
  var liElement = document.createElement('li');
  inputElement.setAttribute('type', 'text');
  inputElement.setAttribute('id', 'name-input-' + i);
  inputElement.setAttribute('class', 'name-input');
  inputElement.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Enter a name for player ' + i);
  liElement.appendChild(inputElement);
  nameInputArray[i] = inputElement;
  document.getElementById('name-list').appendChild(liElement);

  inputElement.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
    if (event.which === 13) {
      var i = parseInt(this.id.charAt(this.id.length - 1));
      console.log(i);
      if(i<numberOfPlayers){
         document.getElementById('name-input-' + (i + 1)).focus();
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<ul id="name-list"></ul>
```

Comment: This throws an error after the last inputbox.  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of null", You need a check against null there.

Comment: @jrook well pointed out my friend, I edited my answer to add atest for `i`.

Comment: the error is because the if statment should be "<" not "<=" But thanks anyways. this was the solution to my problem. using the charAt() was the answer. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with vanilla JS, use this:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= numberOfPlayers; i++) {
  var inputElement = document.createElement("input");
  var liElement = document.createElement("li");
  inputElement.type = "text";
  inputElement.id = "name-input-" + i;
  inputElement.className = "name-input";
  inputElement.placeholder = "Enter a name for player " + i;
  liElement.appendChild(inputElement);
  nameInputArray[i] = inputElement;
  document.getElementById("name-list").appendChild(liElement);
  (function(i) {
    inputElement.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
      if (event.which === 13) {
        alert(this);
        document.getElementById("name-input-" + (i + 1)).focus();
      }
    });
  })(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution.

Do not forget that the created `<li>` element needs to be appended to something like `<body>`. I have actually added a `<ul>` element and appended it to the `<body>` and then appended the `<li>` elements to the `<ul>` element.

If you use `nextSibling`, you do not need to keep elements in `nameInputArray`. I have not removed it to show how it should be initialized before you can use it in your loop. Also, `nextSibling` works in my solution since I have put all the `<li>`s under one `<ul>` which I think is [the correct thing to do anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803630/li-without-parent-tags).

Other than that,  I just corrected a few things here and there. Let me know if you have more questions about this code.

```js
function eventFunc(event) {
  if (event.which === 13) {
    var nextInput = event.target.parentElement.nextSibling.childNodes[0];
    if (nextInput !== null)
      nextInput.focus();
  }
}

var numberOfPlayers = 4;
var nameInputArray = [];

var ulElement = document.createElement('ul');

document.body.append(ulElement);


for (var i = 0; i < numberOfPlayers; i++) {
  var liElement = document.createElement('li');
  ulElement.append(liElement);
  var inputElement = document.createElement('input');

  inputElement.setAttribute('type', 'text');
  inputElement.setAttribute('id', 'name-input-' + i);
  inputElement.setAttribute('class', 'name-input');
  inputElement.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Enter a name for player ' + i);
  inputElement.setAttribute('onkeypress', "eventFunc(event)");
  liElement.appendChild(inputElement);
  nameInputArray[i] = inputElement;
}
```

**UPDATE**: Getting each input box from parent `<li>` elements:

After comment from the OP, I see that they want a structure like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>input box1</li>
    <li>input box2</li>
    <li>input box3</li>
</ul>
```

In this structure, each input box is the first child node of its parent `<li>` element. Therefore, we can still use `nextSibling` (as the OP intended to use) in this way:

```
nextInput = event.target.parentElement.nextSibling.childNodes[0];
```

This line first finds the parent `<li>` element, applies `nextSibling` to get the next `li` element and then gets the input box inside that element.

Comment: Thanks a lot an I do have a <ul> as a parent of the <li> elements. in my code, that is what the following line was for: document.getElementById('name-list').appendChild(liElement);

Comment: so i guess my question is: is focusing on the next li the same thing as focusing on the next input?

Comment: @Osuriel: I am not sure why you want to do this. But I do not think you can get focus on `<li>` elements unless [you define a tabIndex for them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599660/which-html-elements-can-receive-focus).

Comment: And if you want to change your question, please consider posting it as a new question (as follow-up for example). Also, please consider accepting one of the answers if they solve the problem so other visitors can benefit from it.

Comment: @Osuriel: I updated my code. Now each input element is inside its own `<li>`. We can still use `nextSibling`, but we will need to get the parent element first and that is what the *updated* code does.

Comment: Getting just the ~nextSibiling~ did not work for me but his did: 
    event.target.parentElement.nextElementSibling.childNodes[0];

Answer (score -1):

```
$('input').on('keyup', function(event){
  if(event.keyCode == 13){ // 13 is the keycode for enter button
    $(this).next('input').focus();
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jat1merL/

are you looking for this?

by the way, use keyup instead of keypress. if a key is hold it fires mass of keypress events in a speed you can't handle ;)

Comment: Thank you but that does not work because the inputs are inside <li> elements. Thanks a lot anyways.